# JQuery UI Autocomplete is showing more than one items in the autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

JQuery UI Autocomplete is showing more than one search results in the autocomplete area. I have attached the image to show what I mean. I want to show only one in each row.

Is there any css hack to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Please show your code of autocomplete and source

Comment: It depends on how you are actually getting data from the server. Please post your code so we can try to answer.

Comment: Data coming back from server is JSON data like this -

[{"value":21499,"label":"(inside) Interior Design Review"},{"value":193,"label":".Net"},{"value":11543,"label":"100% Biker"}]

Comment: I would advise to use a browser such as chrome or firefox to examine the markup of the autocomplete as it presents. I would imagine that adjusting the css of the autocomplete plugin would be pretty easy. However it's hard to understand why someone would make a plugin that works this way by default.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a stab in the dark but could you possibly add a `display: block;` to the result elements?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try adding below css to fix it

.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is much more efficient if you can fix it on the server side. As I see your response is in JSON format, ensure it is properly formatted before returning on the server. For Autocomplete, you can use JSON Array like structure string on the server side to be returned.